# protect doc with password using Apache POI in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to protect a .doc file with password using apache poi. I am getting this error while running code. please help me

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException: The
>   supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the
>   part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You
>   need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF
>   instead of XSSF)  at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.verifyZipHeader(ZipHelper.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:117)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:257)

```
    POIFSFileSystem fs=new POIFSFileSystem();
    EncryptionInfo info=new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
    Encryptor enc=info.getEncryptor();
    enc.confirmPassword("user");
    OPCPackage opc=OPCPackage.open("D:/Amar.doc", PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
    OutputStream os=enc.getDataStream(fs);
    opc.save(os);
    opc.close();
    FileOutputStream stream=new FileOutputStream("D:/ao.doc");
    fs.writeFilesystem(stream);
    stream.close();
    System.out.println("running");
```

Comment: the error is shown in line                                                                       OPCPackage opc=OPCPackage.open("D:/Amar.doc",PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);

Comment: It looks like you copied the code from the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html). If you had read carefully, then you would also have seen that it is in the section `XML-based formats - Encryption`. For `.doc` files read the section for [binary formats](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#Binary+formats)

Comment: but this code is working fine for .docx format

Comment: Yes, read the link I gave you... Its **all** explained there...

Comment: ok got it thanks......can you please provide me full code to protect doc

Comment: Its in the link too...

Comment: i think those are for xls and ppt only......if I got for doc particularly.it will be easy for me to understand

Comment: `Binary formats (.xls, .ppt, .doc, ...)` the very second line of the website... why wont you just read it???

Answer (score 0):

I checked and reference to Apache POI [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html), it says that the password encryption for .doc file support since version 3.17, so I give it a try.

It must use `HWPFDocument` instead to open your doc file.
Then you need to set password by:

```
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);
```

Complete method:

```
public static void encryptDocFile(File inputDocFile, File outputDocFile, String password) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(inputDocFile);
        BufferedInputStream bufferInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
        POIFSFileSystem poiFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bufferInput);
        // Setting password
        Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);

        HWPFDocument wordDoc = new HWPFDocument(poiFileSystem);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputDocFile);
        wordDoc.write(fileOut);
        bufferInput.close();
        fileOut.close();
        wordDoc.close();
        System.out.println("Encrypted successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to encrypt doc file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or you can checkout the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/chinguyen168/acb1bfbb8679a20a60800b4dc02788b4):

If you have further question or feedback, please let me know. Thank you